@Spy with @InjectMocks in Mockito
I am trying to write unit test for my ProjectsService class. the calss depends on ProjectsRepository. So I annoatetd the repository with @Mock to avoid calling real database and annotate the projectsService with @InjectMocks to inject the required dependencies. Moreover, I want to test some methods in the projects service not all of them. I want to test the assignSharedProjects() method and to mock the call and result of the getSharedProjects(). Below is the test method and the actual method:
@SpringBootTest
public class SharedProjectsServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
            @Spy
    ProjectsService projectsService;

    @Mock
    ProjectsRepository projectsRepository;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws ApiException {
        tokenInfo = new TokenInfo();
        tokenInfo.setUserName("john doe");

        ProjectsEntity mockBenefitProject = new ProjectsEntity();
        mockBenefitProject.setPrjId(70L);

        ProjectsEntity mockBenefitProject2 = new ProjectsEntity();
        mockBenefitProject2.setPrjId(87L);

        SharedProjectsEntity shr1 = new SharedProjectsEntity();
        shr1.setId(new SharedProjectsId(90L, 70L));
        shr1.setBenefitingProject(mockBenefitProject);
        shr1.setSharedPercentage(50.0);

        ProjectsEntity mockOriginalProject = new ProjectsEntity();
        mockOriginalProject.setPrjId(90L);
        mockOriginalProject.setSharedProjects(List.of(shr1));

        when(projectsRepository.findByPrjId(90L)).thenReturn(mockOriginalProject);
        when(projectsRepository.findByPrjId(70L)).thenReturn(mockBenefitProject);
        when(projectsRepository.findByPrjId(87L)).thenReturn(mockBenefitProject2);
}

    @Test
    void testingAssignProjectsToSharedProject() throws ApiException {
        doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(projectsService).getSharedProjects(tokenInfo,90L, 1, 10, "benefitingProjectName", "asc",null);
        doCallRealMethod().when(projectsService).assignSharedProjects(tokenInfo, 90L, Map.of(87L, 40.0, 70L, 20.0),1,10,"benefitingProjectName","asc");
        Object result = projectsService.assignSharedProjects(tokenInfo, 90L, Map.of(87L, 40.0, 70L, 20.0), 1, 10, "benefitingProjectName", "asc");

assertEquals("Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100", result);

}

//The actual method is the ProjectsService Class: 

 public Object assignSharedProjects(TokenInfo tokenInfo, Long OriginalProjectId, Map<Long,Double> sharedProjectsId, int page, int rows,String attr, String sortBy ) throws ApiException{
        ProjectsEntity originalProject = projectsRepository.findByPrjId(OriginalProjectId);
        if(originalProject == null) {
            throw ExceptionConstants.PROJECT_NOT_EXISTS;
        }
        Map<Long, Double> testSharedProjectsId = new HashMap<>(sharedProjectsId);
        double[] sharedPercentage = {0};
        originalProject.getSharedProjects().forEach((c)->{
            if(sharedProjectsId.containsKey(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId())){
                sharedPercentage[0] += testSharedProjectsId.get(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
                testSharedProjectsId.remove(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
            }else{
                sharedPercentage[0] += c.getSharedPercentage();
            }
        });

        if (sharedPercentage[0]>100){
            return new String("Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100");
        }

        for(Long id: testSharedProjectsId.keySet()){
            sharedPercentage[0] += testSharedProjectsId.get(id);
            if (sharedPercentage[0]>100){
                return new String("Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100");
            }
        }

        for(Long sharedProjectId: sharedProjectsId.keySet()){
            ProjectsEntity benefitingProject = projectsRepository.findByPrjId(sharedProjectId);
            if(benefitingProject == null) {
                throw ExceptionConstants.PROJECT_NOT_EXISTS;
            }

            SharedProjectsId id = new SharedProjectsId();
            id.setSharedProjectId(OriginalProjectId);
            id.setBenefitingProjectId(sharedProjectId);

            SharedProjectsEntity sharedProjectsEntity = new SharedProjectsEntity();
            sharedProjectsEntity.setId(id);
            sharedProjectsEntity.setProject(originalProject);
            sharedProjectsEntity.setBenefitingProject(benefitingProject);
            sharedProjectsEntity.setBenefitingProjectName(benefitingProject.getPrjName());
            sharedProjectsEntity.setSharedPercentage(sharedProjectsId.get(sharedProjectId));
            sharedProjectsEntity.setSharedCreatedBy(tokenInfo.getUserName());
            sharedProjectsEntity.setSharedCreatedOn(currentTime());
            sharedProjectsEntity.setSharedUpdatedBy(tokenInfo.getUserName());
            sharedProjectsEntity.setSharedUpdatedOn(currentTime());
            sharedProjectsEntity.setClientName(tokenInfo.getClientName());
            sharedProjectsRepository.save(sharedProjectsEntity);
        }
        return getSharedProjects(tokenInfo,OriginalProjectId, page,  rows, attr,  sortBy ,null);
    } // assign shared projects to original project

I expect to execute the assignSharedProjects method and to reach the return new String("Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100") statement so the assertEquals satisfies. But the actual result is the RunTimeException is thrown, and the method is not executed with the mocked dependencies when I debug it also the method parameters is not passed, and the debugging parameters are projectsRepository 'this' is not available.
I tried to remove the @Spy from the service and use
when(projectsService.getSharedProjects(tokenInfo,90L, 1, 10, "benefitingProjectName", "asc",null)).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);
but it does not work also. the call of projectsService.getSharedProjects is not skipped.
Can you assist on this problem or advise another approach. I want to discard and not call the real method projectsService.getSharedProjects , just to test the assignSaredProjects method?

Why is this a @SpringBootTest when you are not wiring any beans in your test and only creating Mockito mocks that are not in your application context? Why start the application when you are not calling/using anything from the application?

Why do you return new String("something")? You that you can just `return "something;", right? This avoids creating a new object every time.

What is sharedProjectsRepository and where do you initialize it?

I don't know why you expect anything else to happen in your test. You stubbed your methods to throw an exception. Calling the method will throw this exception. You told your code to do something and it does exactly what you told it to.
Here are the relevant snippets from your test and production code:

The projectsService spy is stubbed to throw an exception when the method getSharedProjects is called with the given arguments.
doThrow(RuntimeException.class)
  .when(projectsService)
  .getSharedProjects(tokenInfo, 90L, 1, 10, "benefitingProjectName", "asc", null);


The service's assignSharedProjects method's last statement is: return getSharedProjects(tokenInfo, OriginalProjectId, page,  rows, attr,sortBy, null);
tokenInfo is tokenInfo from your test and stubbed call, OriginalProjectId is 90, page is 1, rows is 10, attr is "benefitingProjectName", sortBy is "asc", null is null.
This is where you call your service's method:
Object result = projectsService.assignSharedProjects(tokenInfo, 90L, Map.of(87L, 40.0, 70L, 20.0), 1, 10, "benefitingProjectName", "asc");



So the test does exactly what the code tells it to. No more, no less.

You wrote:

I expect to execute the assignSharedProjects method and to reach the return new String("Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100") statement so the assertEquals satisfies.

But why would it? Let's have a look at the return statement and required condition:
if (sharedPercentage[0] > 100) {
    return new String("Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100");
}

Okay, so where and how is sharedPercentage calculated?
double[] sharedPercentage = {0};
originalProject.getSharedProjects().forEach((c) -> {
    if(sharedProjectsId.containsKey(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId())) {
        sharedPercentage[0] += testSharedProjectsId.get(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
        testSharedProjectsId.remove(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
    } else {
        sharedPercentage[0] += c.getSharedPercentage();
    }
});

Calculated – rather confusing with side-effectful function instead of looping over the collection or collecting a stream – from the originalProject.getSharedProjects() collection.
Where does the object come from which provides this collection? It's found by querying a repository:
ProjectsEntity originalProject = projectsRepository.findByPrjId(OriginalProjectId);

This projectsRepository is defined as a @Mock in your test. It has 3 calls of the method findByPrjId stubbed:
when(projectsRepository.findByPrjId(90L)).thenReturn(mockOriginalProject);
when(projectsRepository.findByPrjId(70L)).thenReturn(mockBenefitProject);
when(projectsRepository.findByPrjId(87L)).thenReturn(mockBenefitProject2);

Your service is called with id 90, so mockOriginalProject is returned from this stubbed call during your test.
mockOriginalProject has a single shared project: shr1 – which in turn has one benefitting project: mockBenefitProject. mockBenefitObject has project id 70:
final ProjectsEntity mockBenefitProject = new ProjectsEntity();
mockBenefitProject.setPrjId(70L);

final SharedProjectsEntity shr1 = new SharedProjectsEntity();
shr1.setId(new SharedProjectsId(90L, 70L));
shr1.setBenefitingProject(mockBenefitProject);
shr1.setSharedPercentage(50.0);

final ProjectsEntity mockOriginalProject = new ProjectsEntity();
mockOriginalProject.setPrjId(90L);
mockOriginalProject.setSharedProjects(List.of(shr1));

Looking back to your call, we find the following map: Map.of(87L, 40.0, 70L, 20.0). So going through your code (e.g. with pen and paper or with a debugger), we can conclude that sharedPercentage[0] has a value of 20 and does not exceed 100.
But then there's a second loop, which goes over the remaining values of the passed input map.
for (final Double v : testSharedProjectsId.values()) {
    sharedPercentage[0] += v;
    if (sharedPercentage[0] > 100) {
        return "Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100";
    }
}

Value 20 was removed, which means there's only one value left: 40. 40 is added to your percentage variable, resulting in 60. 60 is still not exceeding 100.
The code continues until the end of the function where it calls the method which you have stubbed to throw an exception. (and if you wanted to test that one of the early returns is hit, you wouldn't need to stub this method at all).
The solution? Set up your inputs correctly so that their shared percentage actually exceeds 100.

PS. You don't need the following code, since your service is a spied real instance. A spy always calls the real method.
doCallRealMethod()
  .when(projectsService)
  .assignSharedProjects(
    tokenInfo,
    90L,
    Map.of(87L, 40.0, 70L, 20.0),
    1,
    10,
    "benefitingProjectName",
    "asc");

PPS. It's not correct to use @SpringBootTest together with @Mock, @InjectMocks, and @Spy. If you have a Spring Boot test, use @MockBean, @Autowired, and @SpyBean. If you have Mockito-based test, run it with @ExtendWith(MockitoExtensions.class):
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SharedProjectsServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    ProjectsService projectsService;

    @Mock
    ProjectsRepository projectsRepository;

    @Mock
    SharedProjectsRepository sharedProjectsRepository;

    private TokenInfo tokenInfo;

    // …
}

PPS. Try to avoid side-effects if possible and try to avoid repeat accesses to your maps. Your .forEach "loop" can be simplified from
final double[] sharedPercentage = {0};
originalProject.getSharedProjects().forEach((c) -> {
    if (sharedProjectsId.containsKey(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId())) {
        sharedPercentage[0] += testSharedProjectsId.get(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
        testSharedProjectsId.remove(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
    } else {
        sharedPercentage[0] += c.getSharedPercentage();
    }
});

if (sharedPercentage[0] > 100) {
    return "Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100";
}

for (final Double v : testSharedProjectsId.values()) {
    sharedPercentage[0] += v;
    if (sharedPercentage[0] > 100) {
        return "Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100";
    }
}

to:
double sharedPercentage = originalProject.getSharedProjects()
    .mapToDouble(c -> {
      final Double projectPercentage = sharedProjectsIds.remove(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
      if (projectPercentage != null) {
        return projectPercentage;
      } else {
        return c.getSharedPercentage();
      })
    .sum();

if (sharedPercentage > 100) {
    return "Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100";
}

for (final Double v : testSharedProjectsId.values()) {
    sharedPercentage += v;
    if (sharedPercentage > 100) {
        return "Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100";
    }
}

The first if can even be dropped if the second is moved out of the loop, since it is implicitly covered by the second condition:
double sharedPercentage = originalProject.getSharedProjects()
    .mapToDouble(c -> {
      final Double projectPercentage = sharedProjectsIds.remove(c.getBenefitingProject().getPrjId());
      if (projectPercentage != null) {
        return projectPercentage;
      } else {
        return c.getSharedPercentage();
      })
    .sum();

for (final Double v : testSharedProjectsId.values()) {
    sharedPercentage += v;
}

if (sharedPercentage > 100) {
    return "Total Shared Percentage Exceeds 100";
}

